# How to force ScrollPane fill parent vbox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have ListView inside ScrollPane and ScrollPane inside VBox and all is in SplitPane. How to force ScrollPane to fit and fill VBox. It should by resistant for resizing scene and split pane. I tried do this by adding listener on scene resized and setup pref width and height of scroll pane (taken from parent VBox), but it's not working always.

I do everything in pure java and i want to avoid to use fxml.

Here is sample code

Somewhere in main class (extends Application):

```
private void setupLayout()
{
    BorderPane lvBorderPane = new BorderPane();

    String lvSplitPaneStyle =
            "-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;-fx-padding: 10px";

    SplitPane lvMainContainer = new SplitPane();
    lvMainContainer.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
    lvMainContainer.setStyle(lvSplitPaneStyle);

    VBox mLeftContainer = new VBox();

    mLeftContainer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000");
    mLeftContainer.setMinWidth(140);
    mLeftContainer.setPrefWidth(220);

    VBox lvCenterContainer = new VBox();

    lvCenterContainer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");

    VBox lvRightContainer = new FooBarList(mScene);

    HBox lvBottomContainer = new HBox();

    lvBottomContainer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");
    lvBottomContainer.setMinHeight(40);
    lvBottomContainer.setMaxHeight(40);

    SplitPane lvTopPane = new SplitPane();
    lvTopPane.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);

    lvMainContainer.getItems().addAll(lvTopPane, lvBottomContainer);
    lvTopPane.getItems().addAll(mLeftContainer, lvCenterContainer, lvRightContainer);

    lvBorderPane.setCenter(lvMainContainer);
    mRoot.getChildren().add(lvBorderPane);
}
```

FooBarList class:

```
public class FooBarList extends VBox 
{
    public FooBarList(Scene pmScene)
    {
        this.mWindow = pmScene;
        setupLayout();
    }

    private void setupLayout()
    {
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #000000;");
        this.setMinWidth(240);
        this.setPrefWidth(240);

        mContainer = new ListView<String>();
        ObservableList<String> lvItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("");

        this.mContainer.setItems(lvItems);

        this.mScrollPane = new ScrollPane(mContainer);
        this.getChildren().add(mScrollPane);

        this.mScrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        this.mScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        final VBox lvParent = this;

        mWindow.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                mScrollPane.setPrefWidth(lvParent.getWidth());
            }

        });

        mWindow.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                mScrollPane.setPrefHeight(lvParent.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }

    private ScrollPane mScrollPane;
    private ListView<String> mContainer;
    private Scene mWindow;
}
```

Comment: The ScrollPane must automatically fill the VBox. Can you put in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to depict the issue ?

Comment: Ok wait a moment, i will paste some code.